# What is the correct delivery format for the elements of an Android UI?

Tags: android, user-interface, photoshop, android-resources, android-assets

You have an idea for an Android app and ask a graphic designer to draw up one of the screens in Photoshop. He does that and it looks amazing! But how do you get from *that* to defining what you need in terms of assets for your user interface implementation? In other words, how and in which format should the portrayed UI be delivered to ensure that it can be used by a developer to implement a UI that looks exactly like the UI as portrayed in Photoshop?
I hope I'm making sense here...

UPDATE:

I see that I'm getting negative votes for my question because it's too broad. So here are some specific questions:

1. Where can I find a complete tutorial which describes the process of designing a user interface in Photoshop to implementing the display of that user interface in Android Studio?
2. Which tools are commonly used in the process I have described above?

Comment: While your question is indeed b road, you should not confuse user interface with functionalities. As far as I could tell, you should use the images to have a general "look & feel" to the program, but then, talk to the coder, for him to guide you on expected buttons, program flow and other characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

A screenshot of the UI would be great, it will help us understand the elements and the coding required in android. For example, code for buttons and code for graphs are totally different. You can use images for buttons but you will have to code the graphs completely, you cannot use images for making graphs.

.png formats work well with the graphics for android UI.

There are certain tools which do the job, like this one:

http://exportkit.com/learn/how-to/export-your-psd/convert-a-psd-to-android-xml-ui-and-java